# python3 Gtk program throws introspection typelib error

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk

I am trying to convert a python2 GtK program, specifically [Comix](http://comix.sourceforge.net/), to python3 Gtk program.

I have reached a point where the program throws an error:

> ImportError: cannot import name Gobject, introspection typelib not
>   found

The error is thrown at this point:

```
from gi.repository import Gobject
```

at `bookmark.py`. Anyway the program itself contains various linked py files and it's not that simple to present the structure.

The funny thing is that the same import command is executed in other modules in the same program with no problem. I am not sure what's the problem here.

Some [solutions](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/mepis-64/python-and-gtk-cannot-find-typelib-4175533551/) mentioned as to install `gir1.2-gtk-3.0` is satisfied but to no avail. Also I installed my modules using pip and to compile them using `--enable-introspection=yes` seems an overkill to me. There should be another solution.

Any idea what's going on here and how to deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

module names are case sensitive, try this instead:

```
from gi.repository import GObject
```

Comment: OK you are right. For some reason pycharm cannot report correctly imports from `gi` (they all appear wrong) and I didn't noticed that. Stupid mistake...

Answer (score 0):

if you use Linux  like : Ubuntu, Fedora,...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
```